# Python 2 dict_items.sort() in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm porting some code from Python 2 to 3. This is valid code in Python 2 syntax:

```
def print_sorted_dictionary(dictionary):  
    items=dictionary.items()  
    items.sort()
```

In Python 3, the dict_items have no method 'sort' - how can I make a workaround for this in Python 3?

Comment: Note that the posted code as an indentation error and the function doesn't actually do what it says (it doesn't print anything).

Comment: There was a question on here (I think within the last two or three weeks) about ordered dictionaries in Python. I can't find it but in searching I did find this: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0372/

Comment: Most of the various ordered dict implementations are based on original insertion order, not sorted order. (It would not be all that hard, though, to make a class that implements a tree or that keeps a sorted list alongside a dict.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `items = sorted(dictionary.items())`, it works great in both Python 2 *and* Python 3.

Comment: Making code that works both in Python 2 and 3 seems like an odd plus to me. It makes more sense to me to make good code in the version you're writing for, which includes meaning `2to3` can translate it if you're writing for Python 2.x.

Comment: @Mike, in the general case, sure, but in this case `sorted` is quite fine (nor will `2to3` "correct it, of course) -- so your suggestion and mine are identical and I don't see the point of your criticism in this comment.

Comment: @Alex, I have encountered a lot of people who think writing Python 2/Python 3 polyglots is a good thing. I offered my remark (which wasn't intended to criticize your solution) to clarify to anyone reading this that making code that is valid Python 2 and 3 in the same file is a poor goal.

Answer (score 3):

`dict.items` returns a view instead of a list in Python 3 (somewhat similarly to the `iteritems` method in Python 2.x). To get a sorted list of the items use

```
sorted_items = sorted(d.items())
```

The `sorted` builtin takes an iterable and returns a new list of its items, sorted.